# Are there any good examples or tutorials for UiApp based web apps yet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm fairly experienced with Google Apps Script in Spreadsheets, and want to get going on some web apps, based on the new functionality announced at Google IO 2012.

Are there any decent examples (including source code), or tutorials, for moderately complex UIApp based web apps? So, not just a single page that executes a single function on a button click, but something where there is navigation between different pages/panes etc.

The main thing I'm trying to get my head around so far is navigation in the app - how do I jump around to different views/panes/pages in a web app? Does a web app always have only a single doGet(), and is this only called once at app startup, or can it be re-called with different parameters as the user navigates around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some pretty complex UiApp examples on this site: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples

Answer (score 0):

At IO 2012 we actually announced HtmlService, which lets you build more traditional webapps. UiApp is our existing system. Do you know which fits your needs better?

Comment: UiApp - I don't have enough html experience for HtmlService